# In fear of have committed shirk

Tags: shirk, forgiveness

As-salaam 'Alaykum. I was speaking to my mother about my grandparents and we had gotten to the topic of her being the first born and I said “You are the first thing your parents created together, God created you but you are there first shared thing.” It has caused me emotional distress thinking that I might have committed shirk. Could somebody please tell if I have? In the meantime I will repent and ask Allah for forgiveness.

Answer (score 0):

No. This isn't shirk. And even if you did commit shirk, Allah would still forgive because he is very merciful. Just pray to Allah and ask for forgiveness though.
Allah knows you more than anyone, and he loves you. Mistakes are normal for us to make. Allah is all-forgiving and very merciful.